# Android Reordering ListView items with drag and drop

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop, listviewitem

I have custom ListView with custom Layout consisting of one TextView for display text and another ImageView for long pressing to drag and drop for reordering ListView items like image below.Please help me!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437417/how-to-drag-drop-listview-item-to-another-listview?rq=1,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185802/listview-reorder-items?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice library DSLV.
very smooth and fine working.

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview.